# How to list multiple lightning components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, lightning-apps

I have developed 2 components, the first component will work in the Service cloud and the other component will work in Community. How can I put these two components under the same publish listing? Is this possible or should I create two listings for the two components?

Comment: Are they related to each other (e.g. same feature, just different use cases)? You could likely market this component either way, whichever you think would be more useful.

Comment: They are two components with different functionalities. Like as in one handles the display of reports and the other handles the mail sending functionality.